# XSLT including unwanted elements from outside select criteria

Tags: php, xslt

I have an XSLT to transform HTML to XML that's causing me headaches. Superficially, it works as expected but includes unwanted nodes from what I see as outside the select criteria.

To cut a long story short, there are some HTML elements that, if they end with the string 'if:' seem to break the transformToXML parsing using my XSLT.

I assume this is due to the fact that in XSL, the colon character is used as a namespace separator?

The behavior that I see, when there is an if: at the end of the text in a `<p>` element is that other later elements, which should not be selected by by XSLT:and are not selected if the 'if:' is not present, are selected and moved up the returned XML document.

Here's a sample of the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<p class="SubPartCASA" style="page-break-before:always">
    <a name="_Toc122341660"></a>
    <a name="OPCCaretStart"></a><span class="CharSubPartNoCASA"><span lang="EN-AU">Subpart138.B</span></span><span lang="EN-AU">—</span><span class="CharSubPartTextCASA"><span lang="EN-AU">Certification</span></span>
</p>
<p class="ActHead5"><a name="_Toc122341677"><span class="CharSectno"><span lang="EN-AU">138.075</span></span><span lang="EN-AU"> Key personnel cannot carry out responsibilities</span></a></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif:</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (a) the operator becomes aware that any of its key personnel cannot carry out, or is likely to be unable to carry out, the person’s responsibilities for a period of longer than 30 days; and</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (b) the operator does not tell CASA of the matter mentioned in paragraph(a) within the time mentioned in subregulation(2).</span></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (2) For paragraph(1)(b), the time is:</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (a) if there is not another person authorised to carry out the responsibilities for all or part of the period—24 hours after the operator becomes aware of the matter; or</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (b) if there is another person authorised to carry out the responsibilities for all or part of the period—3 days after the operator becomes aware of the matter.</span></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (3) A person commits an offence if the person contravenes subregulation(1).</span></p>
<p class="Penalty"><span lang="EN-AU">Penalty: 50 penalty units.</span></p>
<p class="ActHead5"><a name="_Toc122341700"><span class="CharSectno"><span lang="EN-AU">138.165</span></span><span lang="EN-AU"> Providing personnel with operations manual</span></a></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif:</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (a) the operator’s operations manual relates to a duty or responsibility of a person who is a member of the operator’s personnel; and</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (b) the operator does not make the part of the operations manual that relates to the duty or responsibility available to the person before the person first begins carrying out the duty or responsibility.</span></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (2) A person commits an offence of strict liability if the person contravenes subregulation(1).</span></p>
<p class="Penalty"><span lang="EN-AU">Penalty: 50 penalty units.</span></p>
<p class="ActHead3" style="page-break-before:always"><a name="_Toc122341701"><span class="CharDivNo"><span lang="EN-AU">Division138.B.9</span></span><span lang="EN-AU">—<span class="CharDivText">Records and documents</span></span></a></p>
<p class="ActHead5"><a name="_Toc122341702"><span class="CharSectno"><span lang="EN-AU">138.170</span></span><span lang="EN-AU"> Personnel training and checking records</span></a></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif:</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (a) a person who is a member of the operator’s personnel undertakes a training activity, obtains a qualification or certificate relating to aerial work operations or gains flying experience; and</span></p>
<p class="paragraph"><span lang="EN-AU"> (b) the following records are not made within 21 days after the person undertakes the activity, obtains the qualification or certificate or gains the flying experience:</span></p>
<p class="paragraphsub"><span lang="EN-AU"> (i) the date the activity was undertaken, the qualification or certificate obtained or the flying experience gained;</span></p>
<p class="paragraphsub"><span lang="EN-AU"> (ii) if the activity was training or a check, flight test, flight review or assessment of competency—whether the training, check, flight test, flight review or assessment was successfully completed.</span></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (2) A person commits an offence of strict liability if the person contravenes subregulation(1).</span></p>
<p class="Penalty"><span lang="EN-AU">Penalty: 50<span style="color:black"> penalty units.</span></span>
</p>


</html>
```

If the colon after an if: is removed, then the offending section either does not move up, if it is below the target tag, or the issue resolves for all lines below if the text in the target tag is fixed:

With 'if:' (just first part to illustrate the issue)

```
 <section text="(1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif:">
        <paragraph text="(a) the operator becomes aware that any of its key personnel cannot carry out, or is likely to be unable to carry out, the person&#x2019;s responsibilities for a period of longer than 30 days; and"/>
        <paragraph text="(b) the operator does not tell CASA of the matter mentioned in paragraph(a) within the time mentioned in subregulation(2)."/>
        <paragraph text="(a) the operator&#x2019;s operations manual relates to a duty or responsibility of a person who is a member of the operator&#x2019;s personnel; and"/>
        <paragraph text="(b) the operator does not make the part of the operations manual that relates to the duty or responsibility available to the person before the person first begins carrying out the duty or responsibility."/>
        <paragraph text="(a) a person who is a member of the operator&#x2019;s personnel undertakes a training activity, obtains a qualification or certificate relating to aerial work operations or gains flying experience; and"/>
        <paragraph text="(b) the following records are not made within 21 days after the person undertakes the activity, obtains the qualification or certificate or gains the flying experience:">
          <paragraphsub text="(i) the date the activity was undertaken, the qualification or certificate obtained or the flying experience gained;"/>
          <paragraphsub text="(ii) if the activity was training or a check, flight test, flight review or assessment of competency-whether the training, check, flight test, flight review or assessment was successfully completed."/>
        </paragraph>
      </section>
      <section text="(2) For paragraph(1)(b), the time is:">
        <paragraph text="(a) if there is not another person authorised to carry out the responsibilities for all or part of the period-24 hours after the operator becomes aware of the matter; or"/>
        <paragraph text="(b) if there is another person authorised to carry out the responsibilities for all or part of the period-3 days after the operator becomes aware of the matter."/>
      </section>
```

With 'if:' changed to 'if', which is the desired result:

```
<section text="(1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif">
        <paragraph text="(a) the operator becomes aware that any of its key personnel cannot carry out, or is likely to be unable to carry out, the person&#x2019;s responsibilities for a period of longer than 30 days; and"/>
        <paragraph text="(b) the operator does not tell CASA of the matter mentioned in paragraph(a) within the time mentioned in subregulation(2)."/>
      </section>
      <section text="(2) For paragraph(1)(b), the time is:">
        <paragraph text="(a) if there is not another person authorised to carry out the responsibilities for all or part of the period-24 hours after the operator becomes aware of the matter; or"/>
        <paragraph text="(b) if there is another person authorised to carry out the responsibilities for all or part of the period-3 days after the operator becomes aware of the matter."/>
      </section>
```

Here's my xslt:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Part>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//html:p[@class='SubPartCASA']"/>


    </Part>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//html:p[@class='SubPartCASA']" priority="1">

    <subpart>

      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-leading-number">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-whitespace">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[@class='ActHead5'][preceding-sibling::html:p[@class='SubPartCASA'][1] = current()]"/>
    
    </subpart>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//html:p[@class='ActHead5']" priority="2">

    <regulation>

      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-decimal-number">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-whitespace">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[@class='subsection'][preceding-sibling::html:p[@class='ActHead5'][1] = current()]"/>
     
    </regulation>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="//html:p[@class='subsection']" priority="3" disable-output-escaping="yes">

    <section>
      <xsl:attribute name="text">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-whitespace">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[@class='paragraph'][preceding-sibling::html:p[@class='subsection'][1] = current()]"/>


    </section>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//html:p[@class='paragraph']" priority="4" disable-output-escaping="yes">

    <paragraph>

      <xsl:attribute name="text">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-whitespace">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[@class='paragraphsub'][preceding-sibling::html:p[@class='paragraph'][1] = current()]"/>


    </paragraph>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//html:p[@class='paragraphsub']" priority="5">

    <paragraphsub>

      <xsl:attribute name="text" >
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      

    </paragraphsub>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="remove-whitespace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '&#x9;&#xA;&#xD;&#10;', ''))" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="get-decimal-number">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' ')" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="get-leading-number">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the PHP Code:

```
<?php
$html = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents(htmlfile));
$input = new DOMDocument();
$input->loadXML($html);
$stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
$stylesheet->load('xsltemplate');

$processor = new XSLTProcessor();
$processor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

$output = $processor->transformToXML($input);

file_put_contents('out.xml', $output);
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you would provide an example of the document these elements that end with 'if:' and it's really hard to help you debug your XSLT if you don't post it for us to see. One snippet of an apply-templates isn't enough to know how it's being processed.

Comment: I suggest you use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` to load the HTML file, rather than treat it as well-formed XML, which it sounds like it isn't (though since you didn't post it, we've no way to know). An HTML parser will likely do a better job of interpreting the content. It may not solve your problem, but it's likely to be a better starting point <https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php>

Comment: By the way, the special role of the `:` character in the names of elements and attributes is not merely a feature of XSLT but is actually an independent XML specification which is used throughout the XML ecosystem <https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/>; it is not strictly part of the core XML spec but effectively it might as well be.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have amended the question with the additional information. I was trying to keep it short as there is a lot of code!

Comment: Please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: P.S. The colon is used as a special character in element and attributes **names**. When it appears inside a **text node** or in an attribute's **value** it's just another character and has absolutely  nothing to do with namespaces.

Comment: The HTML, XSL Template and PHP now represent a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It is nowhere near minimal.

Comment: If you change al `if:` to `if` you have the same problem again. It is nothing to do with namespaces.
See answer of Martin Honnen for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I grasp the current input, it has at least two e.g.

```
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif:</span></p>
<p class="subsection"><span lang="EN-AU"> (1) An aerial work operator contravenes this subregulationif:</span></p>
```

Therefore, if you process the first such `p class="subsection"`, the `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[@class='paragraph'][preceding-sibling::html:p[@class='subsection'][1] = current()]"/>` selects not only the immediately following `p[@class = 'paragraph']` elements but also those following the `p[class = 'subsection']` elements with the same string contents.

Perhaps you want e.g.

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::html:p[@class='paragraph'][generate-id(preceding-sibling::html:p[@class='subsection'][1]) = generate-id(current())]"/>
```